# Relação de slides Flickity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que contém 2 slides.
1 principal e outro relacionado ao mesmo; porém preciso criar um menu de navegação pro slide aparte.

Construi o mesmo da seguinte maneira, gerando 3 slides e utilizando 1 deles para a navegação:

html

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="carousel-navg">
        <li class="carousel-slideg" style="background-color: orange;"> DTexto1</li>
        <li class="carousel-slideg" style="background-color: blue;"> DTexto2</li>

    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-main">
        <div class="carousel-slide" style="background-color: orange;">DTexto1</div>
        <div class="carousel-slide" style="background-color: red;">DTexto2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-nav">
        <div class="carousel-slide" style="background-color: grey;"> "DTexto1"</div>
        <div class="carousel-slide" style="background-color: white;"> "DTexto2"</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

E o jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel-main').flickity({
    prevNextButtons: false,
    pageDots: false
    });
        $('.carousel-nav').flickity({
  asNavFor: document.querySelector('.carousel-main'),
  pageDots: false,
  prevNextButtons: false
});
    $('.carousel-navg').flickity({
  asNavFor: document.querySelector('.carousel-main'),
  contain: true,
  pageDots: false,
  prevNextButtons: false
});
});
```

Gostaria de saber se consigo transformar uma navegação que só fossem botões e não outro slide. Tentei coloca-los como dots, mas o mesmo não reconhece.

Estou utilizando o Flickity para o mesmo. flickity.metafizzy.co

Obrigado.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor mano? não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: Opa, boa noite Rafael. Preciso criar um menu de navegação pros 2 slides. No caso; estou gerando 3 slides e um esta servindo para a navegação.

Comment: Mano acho melhor desenhar pq ainda não estou entendendo kkkkkkkkkkkk, tem algum exemplo de algo parecido?

Comment: Hahahahaha acabei desenvolvendo um parecido; ta nesse link http://suziteresa.com.br/textos.html   . Quando você aperta em um dos textos, por exemplo Depressão (blábláblá) ele muda de slide.